# Dynamic programming with sets

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a typical question in dynamic programming.

My question is given an array = {1,2,3,4,5,6}, I have to find all the arrays whose sum is atmost k. If I consider all the sets, it will become exponential alogorthm.  I thought of achiveng this by Dynamic Programming.

```
Suppose f k =7,
My idea is 
Pass 1: {1],{2}....{6}
Pass 2: Pass1 + {1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5}
Pass 3: Pass2 + {1,2,3},
```

And my algo stops.

Im not able to formulate this with dynamic programming. Any inputs?? How to formulate this algo into program?

Comment: DP is usually used find if such a subset exists or to find number of such subsets. Note that DP will still be exponential if you want all the sets themselves, because there could be exponential number of those.

Comment: Every algorithm for this problem is necessarily exponential in the worst case since there can be exponentially many sets in the solution (let k=sum(array), then you need to return all 2^n subsets).  Maybe you only want to count the number of such sets?

Answer (score 1):

A DP solution for the problem should follow the next recursive formula, and build bottom-up:

```
f(i,0) = {{}} //a set containing only an empty set
f(0,W) = {{}} (W > 0)
f(0,W) = {} (W < 0) //an empty set
f(i,W) = f(i-1,W) [union] extend(f(i-1,w-element[i]),element[i])
```

Where the function extend(set,e) is:

```
extend(set,e):
   for each s in set: //s is a set itself
      s.add(e)
```

Note that complexity could still be exponential (and not even pseudo-polynomial), since the number of sets generated could be exponential, and is stored in the DP table.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is an instance of the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Computational_complexity) whose related decision problem is known to be NP-complete. this means that most certainly there will be no sub-exponential algorithm (though a mathematical proof is missing ).

ZachLangleys comment shows that the enumeration of all solutions would still be exponential in the worst case even if there was an efficient problem solver since producing the output already requires exponential time.

since the decision problem is NP-complete, counting can not be easier (otherwise you'd count and afterwards test the result whether it equals 0 or not).

Comment: Yes, this problem is clearly NP-hard, but counting could be "easier" in that, like knapsack, the problem can be weakly polynomial.  That is, if k is polynomial in n, there may be a poly-time solution.